# Can org agendas be exported to html with a command line script?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

I currently export my org agenda to html by issuing `C-x C-w <NAME OF HTML FILE> RET`. I'd like to have a shell script that does this automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: I was able to get it to write it out with this:

`emacsclient -e '(progn (org-agenda-list) (write-file "agenda.txt"))'`

but my emacs was already running (with the server) with the org file loaded. Do you want it to work without emacs running?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to export *custom agenda views* from the commandline.

```
emacs -eval (org-batch-store-agenda-views) -kill
```

If you use emacsclient, similar to what [jtgd](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/357/jtgd) does, you can use the following command:

```
emacsclient -eval '(org-batch-store-agenda-views)'
```

Both commands will store your [custom agenda views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-agenda-views.html) to the files,
that are configured in the custom agenda views. The process is
described in [the manual section 10.7 Exporting custom agenda
views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-agenda-views.html).

Additionally, you can [extract agenda information](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-agenda-information.html) in machine
readable formats.